# Python - __iter__ method return instance.__str__ and instance.name ?

Tags: python, oop, class, iterator

I am learning OOP python using the [Markana tutorial](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/python_fundamentals_tutorial/oop.html#_lab_16) and I'm having some trouble with Lab 16.8. (Among some other troubles) I can't get the `__iter__` method correct. My method looks like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
        for e in self.l_investments:
            yield e
```

Here is my code (and the result of running it): http://hastebin.com/wayuwakode.py

Here is the result that should appear:

```
>>> 'GOOG' in p
True
```

I get:

```
>>> 'GOOG' in p
False
```

p is an instance of the class Portfolio(). 'GOOG' is the .name property of an instance of the Investment() object. p contains a list and a dictionary of Investment() instances.

I can change my `__iter__` method to yield the names:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for e in self.l_investments:
        yield e.name
```

This fixes it so that `'GOOG' in p == True`, but it breaks another requirement:

```
Failed example:
    for stock in p:
        print stock
Expected:
    1000 shares of APPL worth 252730.00
    5000 shares of CSCO worth 118700.00
    500 shares of GOOG worth 245670.00
    2000 shares of MSFT worth 50880.00
Got:
    APPL
    CSCO
    GOOG
    MSFT
```

How do I change the `__iter__` method (or any other part of the code) so that both of these requirements are met?

I more interested in learning how OOP works than solving this particular problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong thing here - surely you want to change the comparison operation to allow your string to equal the object, rather than trying to hack `__iter__()` to function differently in different situations (which is a terrible idea in general).

Comment: Actually, I'd have to say that the interface requested by that tutorial is a bad idea. Its mixing the interfaces of lists and dicts.  It iterates like a list, but looks up like a dictionary.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is homework; is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add more detail to BrenBarn's answer — yes, you want to override `__contains__`. The `x in object` membership test only uses `__iter__` if `__contains__` isn't defined.

It seems like you'll want to make `__contains__` work for both Investment instances and Investment name strings, since I'd assume you want both `'GOOG' in p` and `investment_object_with_GOOG_name in p` to return `True`. If that's the case, the code should look something like this:

```
def ___contains___(self, item):
    # checks investment name strings by comparing to dictionary keys
    if item in self.d_investments:
        return True
    # checks investment objects by comparing to dictionary values
    if item in self.d_investments.values():
        return True
```

Note that the Investment objects need to implement sensible comparison for this to work.  If they don't (which it looks like they don't — object comparison uses IDs and not attribute contents), either give them a comparison operator, or replace the second half of the above with this version to just do the comparison on the name:

```
    # checks investment objects by comparing to dictionary keys
    if isinstance(item, Investment) and item.name in self.d_investments:
        return True
```

Of course, if you want the membership test to only work for name strings, just remove the second half altogether.

Also, after looking at your code — is there any reason why you keep a list and a dictionary of investments in Portfolio?  Either should be sufficient as an internal representation. I used the dictionary for my code above, but it would be easy to re-implement with a list — I think you should just pick one, unless you really need both for performance or other reasons that I haven't figured out from the code.

Comment: `return getattr(item, 'name', item) in self.investments`

Comment: Excellent! I knew there had to be something like __contains__ ! (Super tough to google for "in" as a keyword.) I used both a list and dict because the tutorial check requires that you look up items by keyword, but that when you iterate over them you return them in the order they were added, which dict can't do.

Comment: @NTUI: check `collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to see what you're trying to do, but I think one possibility is to override `__contains__` on your class to return True if it is passed a string corresponding to the stock's name.  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) .

Answer (score 0):

I think Lattyware has the right answer, define `__eq__` so that the Investment can be equal to a string.

Comment: The problem with this is that for the example the OP shows, you would have both `p == 'GOOG'` and `p == 'APPL'`, which goes against the expectation that equality will be transitive. This gets worse if you consider another investment, `q`, in GOOG only: you have `q == 'GOOG'` and `p == 'GOOG'`, but more than likely *not* `p == q` - investments won't be "equal" just because they have one stock name in common. Testing containment is certainly the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should add an `__eq__` function to your `Investment` class (because that's what you are actually returning.  In this case, you'd want to check if `self.name == other.name`. You can do that, or you can add a `__contains__` function as others have suggested.